# Не работает bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Собственно не работает Bootstrap.

Вот код [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/AwUQ1hHf)

Вот результат [ItImages](http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/14/0107/h_1389124067_3117149_f6876e72e0.png)

На jsfiddle все рботает [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Foodfast/t7kY9/). Обновил ссылку*

Залил на хостинг, все таже картина [тест](http://coffee.e3w.ru/)

Тогда вопрос, почему у меня не работает? Еслт что, использую кубунту 12.10.

Comment: на вид как будто работает. Что именно не так? Может воссоздадите проблему на jsfiddle?

Comment: Там должно быть выпадающее меню, вроде как. И элементы выровнены должны быть. Сейчас попробую

Comment: а в консоле есть ошибки?

Comment: IDE только вот на это ругается: button proprietary attribute "data-target"

Comment: что ж за IDE такая? Оно неправо ругаться. Это вполне корректный атрибут, и ничего плохого в том, что он какой-то свой собственный. Для того data-атрибуты и существуют.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле всё работает. И работает так, как написано. Кнопка, сворачивающая меню, должна быть только на мобильных разрешениях. Она есть, что видно на [скриншоте](http://storage7.static.itmages.ru/i/14/0109/h_1389250984_3357501_365e85b6fa.png).

Она работает. [Тоже видно](http://storage7.static.itmages.ru/i/14/0109/h_1389251155_7244949_29e8647626.png).

То, что она выглядит не очень — так уж написано. Вы можете сделать как предлагают разработчики:

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

и будет [красота](http://storage8.static.itmages.ru/i/14/0109/h_1389251313_3390782_00c70491a9.png).

А если ещё и в имени класса navbar-brand не делать опечаток, то и лого на место встанет.

Успехов!

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Надо же, такая глупая ошибка :)